# Terraform | How to ignore changes for lambda transform params in AWS Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have some Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream resources created via Terraform. Due to a known bug (https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9827) , when lambda transform params are kept default, Terraform avoids them to be written in state file and Every plan/apply is trying to create them again. Because of this issue, I'm trying to add `ignore_lifecycle` to them.

This is one of my resources;

```
resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "some_stream" {
  name        = "some_name"
  destination = ""

  s3_configuration {
    role_arn   = "some_name"
    bucket_arn = "arn:aws:s3:::somebucket"
    prefix = "some/prefix/"
    
    buffer_size = 64
    buffer_interval = 60
    compression_format = "GZIP"

    cloudwatch_logging_options {
      enabled = true
      log_group_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.some_log_group.name
      log_stream_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_stream.some_log_stream.name
    }
  }

  elasticsearch_configuration {
    domain_arn = "arn:aws:es:some-es-domain"
    role_arn   = "arn:aws:iam::some-role"

    index_name = "some-index"
    index_rotation_period = "OneDay"
    buffering_interval = 60
    buffering_size = 64
    retry_duration = 300

    s3_backup_mode = "AllDocuments"

    cloudwatch_logging_options {
      enabled = true
      log_group_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.some_log_group.name
      log_stream_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_stream.some_log_stream.name
    }

    processing_configuration {
      enabled = "true"

      processors {
        type = "Lambda"

        parameters {
          parameter_name  = "LambdaArn"
          parameter_value = "arn:aws:lambda:some-lambda"
        }

        parameters {
          parameter_name  = "BufferSizeInMBs"
          parameter_value = "3"
        }

        parameters {
          parameter_name  = "BufferIntervalInSeconds"
          parameter_value = "60"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the resource above `BufferSizeInMBs` and `BufferIntervalInSeconds` are constantly changing. **I'm trying to ignore these two without touching the `LambdaArn`**  but since all of them are using the same structure below, I couldn't quite figure it out how to do that, I don't even know it's possible or not.

```
parameters {
  parameter_name  = ""
  parameter_value = ""
 }
```

I tried this;

```
lifecycle {
ignore_changes = [elasticsearch_configuration.0.processing_configuration.0.processors]
}
```

But this doesn't exclude the `parameter_name = "LambdaArn"`

To go further,

I tried something like;

```
lifecycle {
  ignore_changes=[elasticsearch_configuration.0.processing_configuration.0.processors[1],elasticsearch_configuration.0.processing_configuration.0.processors[2]]
    ]
  }
```

But it didn't work. It didn't give an error, but didn't ignore the changes either. My Terraform version is `1.1.6` and provider version is `~3.0` `(3.75.1 to be exact)`

Any help will be highly appreciated,

Thank you very much,
Best Regards.

Comment: "But it didn't work." is not specific. What exactly is happening? Do you have any example of errors or undesired output?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, thanks for responding and sorry for the late response, The thing is, `ignore_changes = [elasticsearch_configuration.0.processing_configuration.0.processors.0.parameters]` is working, but when syntax turns to `[elasticsearch_configuration.0.processing_configuration.0.processors.0.parameters[1],[elasticsearch_configuration.0.processing_configuration.0.processors.0.parameters[2]]` it's not giving any errors but doesn't ignore changes too.

Comment: When I search the examples, people generally accomplish that by `[upper.0.lower.0.lowest-block["parameter-1"],upper.0.lower.0.lowest-block["parameter-2"]]` But I don't have that chance because my blocks are not distinctive in terms of structure. Only values are different. Because of this, I couldn't manage it. Is it possible by the way? If it's not possible, I should stick with the one doesn't exclude lambda block. But it would be very cool to figure this out.

Comment: The working one which I mentioned in the first reply doesn't exclude the `parameter_name  = "LambdaArn"`, because of this, I'm digging more to find more exclusive solution.